# Дисперсия оператора Лаппласа в Opencv.js

Tags: javascript, изображения, opencv

Нашёл туториал где определяется размытость изображения http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/ . там используется питон.

```
cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()
```

С помощью вызова .var() считается дисперсия от оператора Лаппласа.
Как посчитать эту же дисперсию, но только в opencv.js, т.к. я хочу определять размытость изображения на фронтенде в браузере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чего там в js не хватает - лапласиана иди дисперсии?

Если второго, то должна быть функция [meanStdDev](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga846c858f4004d59493d7c6a4354b301d), с помощью которой можно получить стандартное отклонение, а дисперсия - квадрат стандартного отклонения

```
 variance = std * std
```

Comment: есть, но как получить из него значение дисперсии, чтобы сравнить с другим. вот как я сейчас использую, мне нужно получить значение дисперсии отсюда.

cv.meanStdDev(laplace, mean, std)

Comment: std в квадрате. собственно, для целей сравнения своих кадров и не обязательно дисперсию брать

Comment: мне не с кадрами сравнивать, а с просто константой, чтобы понять размыто или нет

Comment: Попробую std в квадрат

Comment: вот эта константа будет  иметь другое значение , и распределение будет не таким крутым, если в квадрат не возводить.

Comment: если поможет, то весь код вот он

`let laplace = new cv.Mat()
 let gray = new cv.Mat()
 cv.cvtColor(image, gray, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
 cv.Laplacian(image, laplace, cv.CV_64F)
 let std = new cv.Mat()
 let mean = new cv.Mat()
 cv.meanStdDev(laplace, mean, std)`

Comment: и я просто должен в квадрат std возвести здесь?

Comment: здесь std - матрица с одним каналом (поскольку серая картинка). его значение нужно возвести в квадрат

Comment: я не могу возвести *std* в квадрат, т.к. в javascript это объект

Comment: я же говорю, что это не скаляр, а  одномерная матрица, содержащая cт. отклонения по каналам. Нужно извлечь значение нулевого канала и его в квадрат.

Comment: а если использовать `cv.Scalar`?

Comment: Я не знаю, как оно в JS, но scalar обычно кортеж (tuple) из четырёх double. В С++ к элементу матрицы можно обратиться через at `M.at<double>(0,0);`

Comment: да я знаю как в с++, вот с js мучаюсь...

Comment: [Оно?](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d06/tutorial_js_basic_ops.html) let R = src.ucharAt(row, col * src.channels()); ну только не uchar

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: `std.channels()`  просто единицу возвращает на любом изображении

Comment: Да почему channels-то?? Это количество каналов, для серой матрицы -  1. А сами данные  src.floatAt(0,0) или как там будет в вашем бестиповом языке.